# How to replace in VueJS some selected text with an Element-UI button in runtime?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm new in VueJS and I'm developing a sort of tagging editor. It is supposed to be pretty basic.

The idea is that I have a list of tags and some document text. The goal is replacing the selected text with a button (the tag) which, on click, shows the infos of that tag.

Until now I've been able to replace the selected text with a button through a method using `window.getSelection()` and reassigning its innerHTML.

I have two issues using this solution:

1) I'm able to replace innerHTML only with raw HTML, so it's not working for Element-UI components, which I would like to use.

2) Moreover, if I replace the innerHTML with a button it works fine. The issue is that I'm not able to link any function to the button. So if I replace my selected innerHTML with `var newHTML = "<button @click="someFunction">"+text+"</button>"`, the function is not triggered on click.

I hope I've been clear enough explaining my issues.

Comment: Stop trying to manipulate the dom and instead use the VDOM. Then you can use `v-if` statements or `conditional rendering`

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I guess then I'll study a little bit more about VDOM manipulation, because until now I've been unable to find a way to manipulate arbitrary any kind of selection (one char, one word, multiple words), by manipulating only the VDOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to find that replicating this functionality in Vue (or similar) is going to take a bit more work.

Just quickly thinking about it... You would need to render your text block as a series (array of objects, likely) of elements using [list rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) (or in the [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#v-if-and-v-for)). Each element would either be plain text or a tag button and rendered accordingly. When using Window.getSelection(), you will need to determine which (if any) of your text elements should handle the selection. That node would then need to be split into three (text before, button, text after) and updated in your array. Vue will then take care of rendering those elements out for you.

Another possibility you could consider would be to use/extend existing components to get what you need. Some potential examples might be [ProseMirror](https://prosemirror.net/) or [tiptap](https://tiptap.scrumpy.io/). I have no experience whatsoever with these, so couldn't really help beyond a quick Google search. They may be a bit heavy for what you need. They might be perfect.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply.
I've been thinking at this approach either. The thing is that I'm out of ideas on how managing multiwords selection. That's the reason why I found manipulating the DOM an easier way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Added a suggestion for you.

Comment: Thank you. At the end I've just saved my doc text in a string, as suggested by you, and when I tag some selected text, I split the string in three parts: first part of doc, the tag text (with tag flag = true), last part of doc. I keep everything in an array and work recursively on it every time I tag something. Then, in my template, I display the entire doc with a v-for cycle, and use the right component by using "component :is" according to the flag of each object.
This approach is working good enough for me, even though there are many cases and considerations to keep in mind.